# What's the kind of function that satisfies $\lim _{|x|,|y| \rightarrow \infty} f(x)-f(y) \rightarrow 0$ when $|x|-|y|=c$ where c is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Actually I'm looking for a kind of function satisfies $\lim _{|x|,|y| \rightarrow \infty} f(x)-f(y) \rightarrow 0$ when $|x|-|y|=c$ ($x,y \in R^{n}$) where c is a constant, for example, $f=log(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2})$ satisfies this, I want to know if this kind of function has a name or there are studies about this kind of function.

Comment: Is $f$ defined in one or two variables? Or how?

Comment: in $R^{n}$, for example in $R^{2}$, $f(x)=f(x_{1},x_{2})$, $(x_{1},x_{2}) \in R^{2}$.

Comment: If $f$ is spherically symmetric, viz. $f(x)=g(\|x\|)$, and if $g(r) \to L$ as $r\to \infty$ or $g$ is slowly varying at infinity (as  in your example), then $f$ will do . I cannot think of other type of functions like this.